# Writing to a text file does not occur in real-time. How to fix this

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that takes a long time to run.

I placed print-outs throughout the script to observe its progress.
As this script different programs, some of whom print many messages, it is unfeasible to print directly to the screen.

Therefore, I am using a report file

```
f_report = open(os.path.join("//shared_directory/projects/work_area/", 'report.txt'), 'w')
```

To which I print my massages:

```
 f_report.write(" "+current_image+"\n")
```

However, when I look at the file while the script is running, I do not see the messages. They appear only when the program finishes and closes the file, making my approach useless for monitoring on-going progress.
What should I do in order to make python output the messages to the report file in real time?

Many thanks.

Comment: How do you "look at the file while the script is running"?

Comment: I use notepad++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use **flush()** function to write immediately to the file.

```
f_report.write(" "+current_image+"\n")    
f_report.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
newbuffer = 0
f_report = open(os.path.join("//shared_directory/projects/work_area/", 'report.txt'), 'w', newbuffer)
```

it sets up a 0 buffer which will push OS to write content to file "immediately". well, different OS may behavior differently but in general content will be flushed out right away.

Comment: @pingul , it sets up a 0 buffer which will push OS to write content to file "immediately". well, different OS may behavior differently but in general content will be flushed out.